# Laurent Series of $\frac{e^z}{z(1+z^2)}$ [at z=0]

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, laurent-series

How to get the Laurent Series of $$\frac{e^z}{z(1+z^2)}$$ at $z=0$?
I know the answer is

$$\frac{1}{z} + 1 - \frac{1}{2}z - \frac{5}{6}z^2 + \frac{13}{24}z^3 + \frac{101}{120}z^4 + O(z^5)$$

But I don't know how to do it, wanna know the step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple formula for that. You know that$$\frac{e^z}{1+z^2}=\left(1+\frac z{1!}+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}\cdots\right)\left(1-z^2+z^4-z^6+\cdots\right).$$You compute the first few terms and then you divide by $z$ to get the Laurent series.

Comment: Which is equivalent to use the Taylor expansion of $\frac{e^z}{1+z^2}$ and then divide by $z$.

Comment: @Thern Yes, sure.

Comment: @awc789 I'm glad I could help.